# Debugging failed elasticsearch query

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch

When searching through a symfony2 view I get the following error:

```
Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{
  "query": {
    "text": {
      "name": {
        "query": "physics",
        "analyzer": "snowball"
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 10000
}]]

Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParsingException: [courses] No query registered for [text]
```

Comment: Have you tried posting the issue to symfony2? They are generating an invalid query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using query which is called "text". Elasticsearch doesn't contain such a query type. Here you have all query types that ES supports:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-queries.html

You probably wanted to use this query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "name": {
                "query": "physics",
                "analyzer": "snowball"
            }
        }
    },
    "size": 10000
}
```